# Trouble filtering data frame in R

Tags: r

I imported csv file into dataset. Now I want to copy a 48-row block of data starting from i-th row into a new dataframe then to skip over 3 48-row blocks and then to append the 4th 48-row block to the new dataframe's end, so on until the end of dataframe. 
I spent many hours on this issue without any success.
Thanks in advance for any possible hint.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple oneliner:

```
new.df <- old.df[ c( rep( F, i - 1 ), rep( T, 48 ), rep( F, 48 * 3 ), rep( T, 48 ) ), ]
```

but hey, let's make it simpler:

```
new.df <- old.df[ c( rep( F, i - 1 ), rep( c( T, F, F, F, T ), each=48 ) ), ]
```

or even

```
new.df <- old.df[ i - 1 + which( rep( c( T, F, F, F, T ), each=48 ) ), ]
```

Explanation:

We create a vector of true / false values; the rows that correspond to T will be selected. We use c() to concatenate the blocks. First, we skip i - 1 (F), then we take 48 (T), then we skip 3 * 48, and we take one 48 again.

Comment: adding the `FALSE` is not necessary. In other words, just ask for the ones you need, you don't have to tell the df what you dont want.

Comment: clearly, we have a student / beginner here, and I like to promote the ability to select rows / columns of df's using T/F vectors, because then using a logical selector comes naturally.

Comment: Thanks for the oneliner and explanation. It helped!

Comment: Than you are ready for the second part, see the updated answer :-)

Comment: The third version is cool! One thing I couldn't find in your code is that it doesn't cycle till the end of the data frame. Anyway, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:1000, y = rnorm(1000))
> dim(df)
[1] 1000    2
# see that it has 1000 rows.
# let's say I want to copy 48 rows from row 102
new_df <- df[102:(102+48), ]
# or I do it with a variable
i <- 102
j <- i + 48
new_df <- df[i:j, ]
# If you need an uneven range, just make a vector
# Either specify a range of rows or just row numbers
rows_i_want <- c(1:48, 52, 55, 100:120, 128)
new_new_df <- df[rows_i_want, ]
```

Below is an example of a general function to do this for any `data.frame`

```
# This function takes a data.frame and a starting index and a block size
keep_rows <- function(df, i, block = 48) {
    # Grab the number of rows remaining in the df from i to end
    nr <- nrow(df[i:nrow(df), ])
    if(i>nr)
        stop("index is too high")

    start <- seq(i, nr, by = block)

    if(length(start)==1)
        stop("index is too high")

    end <- c(start[2:length(start)], nrow(df))
    df2 <- data.frame(start, end)
    ranges <- apply(df2, 1, function(x) { x[[1]]:x[[2]]})
    to_keep <- rep(c(T,F,F,F,T), floor(round(nr/block)))
    return(df[to_keep[1:length(ranges)],])
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed code very much, Maiasaura! I didn't understand why you use `length(ranges)` isn't it the same as `floor(round(nr/block)))` ?
Anyway, `df.new<-df[rep(rep(c(T,F),c(48,144)),nr/192),]` did the trick for me. Thanks again for your post, much appreciated!